# UPS API - What encoding should I use?

Tags: c#, api, encoding

I'm implementing shipping into my application and I have problems with polish chars. On generated label they appear as '?'. Client is written in C# so all my strings are Unicode. Maybe you know in what encoding I should send data to get polish chars?

I send:

gęśla jaźń

And on the .gif label there is:

g??la ja??

It seems that UPS expected text in different encoding, but I can't find which.

The code:

```
 ShipToType upsShipTo = new ShipToType();
 upsShipTo.Name = shipToNameTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: Where are you fetching this data from? How? Show some sample code.

Comment: from textbox in winform application. Code is simple assignment: upsObject.ShipTo.Name = shipToNameTextBox.Text;

Comment: Try to identify where are those characters lost by debugging your application. Is `shipToNameTextBox.Text` properly encoded?

Comment: it's enetered by user via application interface, see edited question to

Comment: @Adrian Serafin, what UPS? What .gif label? What you are talking about? Post some sample code that illustrates the problem or your question cannot be answered.

Comment: UPS is worldwide courier company. They have API to generate orders for them. I use it and as receiver send person name with some polish characters. Is it clear know? The code doesn't matter because it works. The only problem is encoding.

Comment: @Adrian Serafin, if the code works why are you asking this question? If you have encoding problems then obviously your code doesn't work. To say why it doesn't work you will need to show it or we are wasting our time in useless comments instead of solving problems :-)

Comment: Code itself is irrelevant. I just need to know what encoding API expects...

Comment: Well, then you should probably ask UPS, assuming that you have already looked into the API documentation and not found anything there.

Comment: I looked and not found ;) I ask here because I hoped it would be quicker. I have to wait few days before anyone from ups answers me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got answer from UPS: api uses latin1 charset so it doesn't support polish chars.